# What is the difference between ~directory_name and /directory_name in linux

Tags: macos, shell, cd

I am using a Mac OS 10.10.3 and I am new to using linux commands.
This is the doubt I have-

The present working directory: 
/dir_name

when I run this command:
cd ~

The directory path changes to:
~dir_name

What does the ~ or / change in the directory path mean?

Comment: Mac OS does not use the Linux kernel and is not a Linux system. `cd` is a shell command, not a Linux command. Both Mac OS (version 10 and later) and Linux are UNIX-like systems.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson for clearing up my fundamentals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` by itself is equivalent to `$HOME`. It refers to your home directory, typically something like `/home/yourname`.

`~foo` refers to the home directory of the user `foo`.

Both these uses of `~` are handled by the shell. That means, for example, that if you call `fopen("~/foo/file.txt", "r")` in a C program, it won't expand `~` to your home directory; rather, it will look for (and probably not find) a directory literally named `~` in the current directory.

`/` is the root directory.

Invoking `cd` with no argument is equivalent to `cd ~` or `cd $HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

`cd ~` redirect you to home directory.
It is equivalent to `cd $HOME`

`cd /`  redirect you to root directory

Answer (score 1):

~ is shorthand for your home directory.  / will change to the root directory.  So

`cd ~` changes directory to your home directory

`cd /` changes to root directory.

Answer (score 0):

~ is shorthand for current user's home directory or that is yours.

/ is shorthand for root directory

You can `pwd` command (outputs the path) to see what's the difference.

```
cd ~
pwd
cd /
pwd
```